# How to drop duplicated rows in a dataframe and then intergrate rows with same column given

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

Please show me how to convert this dataframe to the following format in python code, thank you!!!

[image]

since some raws are repeatedly appear with same column names as image1 shown, the result should contain less raws after intergration and dropping of redundancies

Comment: please provide your datasets as **text**, not images

Comment: Please reduce your problem into a simple, reproducible sample and provide it copy-&-pastable. See [Help others reproduce the problem ...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned it is kind of hard to answer without a usable data sample, but this solution based on random sample might help you:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

brands = ['jaguar', 'volvo', 'toyota']
years = [2019, 2020, 2021, 2022]
actions = ['showroom', 'testdrive', 'call']

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['brand'] = random.choices(brands, k=22)
df['year'] = random.choices(years, k=22)
df['action'] = random.choices(actions, k=22)

pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['brand', 'year', 'action']).size()).unstack('action').fillna(0)
```